# jquery: get value of button by attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page and it have multiple buttons. These buttons are generated dynamically. you can see in below example value of **data=** is generated dynamically.

```
<a id="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#Modal" data-toggle="modal" data="26" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a id="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="23" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a id="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="22" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
```

i am trying to get the value of data in jquery.

```
myvar1= $('#btn-classified').attr('data');
    alert(myvar1);
```

But problem is all the time i am getting **26** as output.
I am not sure what am i doing wrong.

Please advise.

Comment: **ID should be unique**.

Comment: When do you want to get the value?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. I got the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` need to be unique. If you want to add event to all of these link you can select a common selector like `name` or `class`

```
$("a[name='btn-classified']").on('click',function(event){
alert($(this).attr('data'))
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gqj8b9um/)

Answer (score 2):

You have the same id on all buttons so only one of them is used. Ids should be unique. You need to give them different ids or classes to access them with.

Answer (score 2):

```
                <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a id="btn-classified1" name="btn-classified" data-target="#Modal"
                    data-toggle="modal" data="26" class="btn-home"
                    href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
                <a id="btn-classified2" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal"
                    data-toggle="modal" data="23" class="btn-home"
                    href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
                <a id="btn-classified3" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal"
                    data-toggle="modal" data="22" class="btn-home"
                    href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                $('.btn-home').each(function(){
                       alert($(this).attr("id"));      
                     });
                 </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: +1, for your right answer, but try to keep answer in short only provide code where changes is required. without unnecessary code. I think here HTML code not required in answer because  in question he has already provided.

Answer (score 1):

if you are generating buttons dynamically, try building id also like that so that id remains unique. Here the problem is with ur ID as id of all ur btns are similar , it will pick only the first value.

here is a sample PHP code for the above

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++): ?>
    <button id="<?php echo 'idName_'.$i ?>" data="<?php echo 'data_'.$i ?>" onClick=clickAction(<?php echo $i ?>) >
<?php endfor; ?>

<script>
function clickAction(i){
    myvar1= $('#idName_'+i).attr('data');
    alert(myvar1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate IDs for elements. IDs must be unique. You can modify the dom to have same class. Like this:

```
<a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#Modal" data-toggle="modal" data="26" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="23" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="22" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
```

And then target them using class selector and iterate using `.each()` to get respective attribute values:

```
 $('.btn-classified').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data'))
 });
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('.btn-classified').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data'))
 });
```

```html
   <a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#Modal" data-toggle="modal" data="26" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="23" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<a class="btn-classified" name="btn-classified" data-target="#ApplyModal" data-toggle="modal" data="22" class="btn-home" href="javascript:void();" data-original-title="" title="">Apply</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="get_value" value="2">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var val = $("#get_value").attr('value');
   alert(val);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Hi First thing is that 'id' should be unique and You can use jquery each function:

```
$( "a.btn-home" ).each(function( index ) {
   var btn_val= $(this).attr('data');
});
```